# Using Option with cleaner code

Tags: scala, scala-option

Apologies if this is a newbie question... 
In Scala I understand that it is preferred to use an `Option` rather than returning `null` when you have a function which returns an instance but could potentially return nothing. I understand that this makes it better with regards to safety, because you are not passing null references around, and risking `NullPointerException` somewhere down the line.

However, is there a cleaner way to handle options than using pattern matching? 
The syntax I end up using is the following:

```
val optObj : Option[MyObject] = myFunctionThatReturnsOption
optObj match {
  case Some(obj) => {
  //my code using obj
  }

  case None => _
}
```

In reality all this doing is the equivalent of the Java version:

```
MyObject obj = myMethodThatCanReturnNull()
if (obj != null) {
  //my code using obj
}
```

Is there some other way to avoid all this boilerplate in Scala when using `Option` instead of `null` references? All I want to do is execute a piece of code as long as the `Option` contains some object (i.e. is not `None`).

Comment: `Option` is *not* about safety actually; it's about being able to handle missing values more easily.

Comment: Well yes, but easily is a bit of an ambiguous term. Having `if (obj != null) {} else {}` is definitely easy (arguably easier). The reason for using Scala is supporting such things in a typesafe and more correct way... :)

Comment: `if not null ... else null` is easy if you do it once but not if you have a chain of functions that can return `null`; futhermore, I'd even say `foo.map(_.bar)` *is* easier *and* shorter than `if (foo != null) foo.bar else null`, and also much more readable after a while.

Comment: http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `foreach`, `getOrElse` and/or `map` if you want to work in a more consistent way. Here's some use cases and what I'd do:

```
 //I want to get a non-null value and I have a sane default
 val result = myOption getOrElse 3

 //I want to perform some side effecting action but only if not None
 myOption foreach{ value =>
   println(value toString ())
 }
 //equivalently
 for(value <- myOption){
   //notice I haven't used the "yeild" keyword here
 }

 //I want to do a computation and I don't mind if it comes back as an Option
 val result = for(value <- myOption) yield func(value)
 val equivalent = myOption map func
```

The third example will use `map` in both cases.

It gets really interesting when you can mix and match things in a "for comprehension" (Google term.) Let's say that `func` also returns an `Option` but I only want things working in specific cases:

```
 val result = for{ 
   value <- myOption if value > 0
   output <- func(value)
 } yield output
```

Now I get back an `Option` but only if `myOption` contained an integer that was greater than zero. Pretty nifty stuff, no?

Comment: Thanks, the `for` approach (the 2nd one) looks clean too. I dislike the fact that they called the first approach `foreach` when there is just one value in an `Option`, makes readability for newbies like me difficult, but anyway at least its cleaner than a pattern match.

Comment: @wheaties: I think you forgot to add a `flatMap` example.

Comment: @jbx: it's a known problem (which many don't see as a problem but I do) that `for` is not really the perfect word for this; Haskell uses the more neutral `do` instead.

Comment: @ErikAllik Oh, yes the Haskell word is definitely a bit more appropriate. Yes, coming from Java which is more verbose but promotes correct naming of both variables and methods, I often find Scala difficult just because of the naming (especially function arguments just named `p` or `z`!). Well, I guess its a question of getting used to it too.

Comment: Another alternative which is maybe a bit more adequately named is using the `exists` method too, if the code is returning `boolean`.

Comment: I think good naming is relative/subjective... sometimes short names are better if it's obvious what they mean or if the method is too generic to come up with a meaningful/descriptive name. Like for example `def fact(n: Int)`—`n` is a perfectly good name here; or `head[T](xs: List[T]): T = ...`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `foreach` if you just want to perform some side-effecting operation with the value:

```
optObj.foreach(obj => {
    //my code using obj
})
```

if you have some other use case you should use some other method on `Option` like `map`, `filter` or `getOrElse`.

Comment: Oh, for some reason I associated `forEach` with iterable things like Lists etc., which is why I missed it... Scala's method naming tend to be so obscure sometimes! Yeah `getOrElse` I am familiar with, but in that case a pattern match would be better (for my case), because there is no way to execute side-effects on the normal case where `get` returns a value.

Comment: The naming is to be consistent with other containers.  Think of an `Option` as being a container that can hold either exactly one or zero items.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the way I usually use options if I only care about present value is foreach:

```
optObj.foreach { obj => 
 //...
}
```

Having said this, there are a lot of other options (which @wheaties enlisted) and some people keep battling about the true one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `flatMap`-method pretty well with `Option`. Like hier:

```
case class Player(name: String)
def lookupPlayer(id: Int): Option[Player] = {
  if (id == 1) Some(new Player("Sean"))
  else if(id == 2) Some(new Player("Greg"))
  else None
}
def lookupScore(player: Player): Option[Int] = {
  if (player.name == "Sean") Some(1000000) else None
}

println(lookupPlayer(1).map(lookupScore))  // Some(Some(1000000))
println(lookupPlayer(2).map(lookupScore))  // Some(None)
println(lookupPlayer(3).map(lookupScore))  // None

println(lookupPlayer(1).flatMap(lookupScore))  // Some(1000000)
println(lookupPlayer(2).flatMap(lookupScore))  // None
println(lookupPlayer(3).flatMap(lookupScore))  // None
```

Comment: not sure why you're showing the first 3 `println`s there... you almost always want `flatMap` in that case.

Comment: @ErikAllik I think he wants to show me the difference between using `map` and `flatMap`, i.e. that it extracts the Option

Comment: ah well, that's true :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great reference for Scala best practices regarding options:
http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/index.html